# Obtaining features from EBGaramond font in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, fontspec, context, ebgaramond

I want to use EBGaramond font "historic" features in ConTeXt the same way as I could use them from LaTeX but without success. I think I am missing something in my ConTeXt but I am not able to see what it could be. I put 2 examples to show what I am after. 
LaTeX (working) example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Contextuals=Alternate,Numbers=OldStyle,RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+cv03,+dlig}}

\setmainfont[RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+cv03,+ss05,+dlig,+cv91},Ligatures=Historic]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

session
univers
Que
Quelconque
Joseph
Â¶

\end{document}
```

ConTexT (partially not working) example:

```
\enableregime[utf]
\language[fr] % french hyphenation

\definefontfeature[oldstyle][calt=yes,onum=yes,ss02=yes,cv01=yes,cv03=yes,ss05=yes,dlig=yes,cv91=yes,hlig=yes,liga=yes]

\definefontfamily[mainfont][serif][EBGaramond][features=oldstyle]
\setupbodyfont[mainfont, 8pt]

\starttext

session
univers
Que
Quelconque
Joseph
Â¶

\stoptext
```

From pdf output, I see that s are not converted to long s, leading u is not converted to v, and middle v not to u, and Q do not have long tail. J (+cv03) and pilcrow (+cv91) are displayed properly however.

Building LaTeX sample with XeTeX and LuaTeX give same output.

Comment: Do both methods use the same fonts? On my system, ConTeXt uses the opentype fonts included in TeX Live, while LuaLaTeX uses versions installed for the system. On the other hand, the fonts appear to be identical.

Comment: I use texlive 2015 without extra fonts (I've checked ebgaramond is not in fonts directory) and I've installed fonts in c:/Windows/fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code (except the \enableregime, which is obsolete but won't do any harm). However, it doesn't work - I have no clue why. When you define and add the font features one by one, they do work (this may be a bug with the context font loading mechanism, I remember that the ebgaramond font was mentioned several times on the list). So my example would be:

```
\definefontfeature[f:cv01] [cv01=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:cv03] [cv03=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:cv91] [cv91=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:calt] [calt=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:dlig] [dlig=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:hlig] [hlig=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:liga] [liga=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:onum] [onum=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:ss02] [ss02=yes]
\definefontfeature[f:ss05] [ss05=yes]

\definefontfamily [mytest] [serif] [EBGaramond]
\setupbodyfont [mytest,14pt]

\startTEXpage
{\addff{f:cv01} \addff{f:cv03} \addff{f:cv91} \addff{f:calt}\addff{f:onum} \addff{f:ss02} \addff{f:ss05} \addff{f:dlig} \addff{f:hlig} \addff{f:liga}

official fist fiction

session

univers

Que

Quelconque

Joseph

Â¶}
\stopTEXpage
```

Which gives:

[image]

Which is what you were expecting, I guess. However, I share the comment about these features: they are nice toys and good for showcasing these things, but you wouldn't want to do any serious philological typesetting with them; there are too many exceptions to these rules.

Comment: Using latest standalone ConTeXt beta works as well with my "original" MWE. Thanks a lot.